# Aggregated munin graphs file is empty

Tags: munin, graph

I'm unable to aggregate some custom graphs I wrote. I know aggregation is functional, because I'm able to aggregate default plugins, but am unsure what's wrong with mine.

munin.conf:

```
[myapp;web-servers;0-1]
        address 1.2.3.4
        use_node_name yes
[myapp;web-servers;0-2]
        address 5.6.7.8
        use_node_name yes

[myapp;web-servers;Aggregated]
        update no

#does not work:
    node_aggregate.graph_args --base 1000 -l 0
    node_aggregate.graph_title Aggregated connects
    node_aggregate.conns.label conns
    node_aggregate.conns.sum myapp;web-servers;0-1:nodejs_numberOfConnects.conns myapp;web-servers;0-2:nodejs_numberOfConnects.conns


#works:
    node_aggregate.graph_title Aggregated cpu
    node_aggregate.cpu.label cpu.user
    node_aggregate.cpu.sum myapp;web-servers;0-1:cpu.user myapp;web-servers;0-2:cpu.user
```

My plugins looks like this:

```
if [[ "$PARAM" == "numberOfConnects" ]]; then
        echo "graph_title Active Connects";
        echo "graph_info Active Connects";
        echo "graph_vlabel Connections";
        echo "$PARAM.label conns";
        echo "$PARAM.type GAUGE";
        echo "$PARAM.colour 0927EB"
        exit 0;
elif ...
fi
echo $PARAM.value 15
```

For testing purposes I can hardcode "$PARAM.value 15". I can then do
`munin-run --servicedir /etc/munin/plugins nodejs_numberOfConnects` which will return `numberOfConnects.value 15`

And the error I get is:

```
==> /var/log/munin/munin-graph.log <==
2016/03/15 13:57:01 [ERROR] filename is empty for $VAR1 = {
  '#%#name' => 'z1_0',
  'cdef' => 'z1_0,UN,0,z1_0,IF',
  'graph' => 'no',
  'label' => 'z1_0'
};
, myapp;web-servers;0-1:nodejs_numberOfConnects.conns

2016/03/15 13:57:01 [ERROR] filename is empty for $VAR1 = {
  '#%#name' => 'z1_1',
  'cdef' => 'z1_1,UN,0,z1_1,IF,z1_0,ADDNAN',
  'colour' => undef,
  'draw' => undef,
  'graph' => 'yes',
  'label' => 'conns'
};
, myapp;web-servers;0-2:nodejs_numberOfConnects.conns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass ***conns*** as the exported value, but that's actually ***numberOfConnects***

```
node_aggregate.nodejs_numberOfConnects.label conns(or whatever)
node_aggregate.nodejs_numberOfConnects.sum \ 
    myapp;web-servers;0-1:nodejs_numberOfConnects.numberOfConnects \ 
    myapp;web-servers;0-2:nodejs_numberOfConnects.numberOfConnects
```

Comment: hey, I just wrote the same thing :O

Answer (score 1):

After much debugging I realized I was incorrectly using the name of the **label** instead of the name of the **value**.

```
node_aggregate.conns.sum myapp;web-servers;0-1:nodejs_numberOfConnects.conns myapp;web-servers;0-2:nodejs_numberOfConnects.conns
```

needs to be

```
node_aggregate.conns.sum myapp;web-servers;0-1:nodejs_numberOfConnects.numberOfConnects myapp;web-servers;0-2:nodejs_numberOfConnects.numberOfConnects
```

because of

```
if [[ "$PARAM" == "numberOfConnects" ]]; then
[...]
echo $PARAM.value 15
```

In other words, in my case the server line equals to:
`$arbitraryname1.arbitraryname2.sum $clientname;$hostgroup;$hostname:$pluginname.$valuename`

I was also very much thrown away by the `cpu` example which uses the following syntax:
 `myapp;web-servers;0-1:cpu.user` but that's because its value name actually coincides to the label name!!